# Transforming every inner pack of a nested pack

Tags: c++, templates, variadic

Here, as an example, I will try to rotate the templates arguments in a pack to the left by N, but I want this done to every inner pack of a nested pack as well.  The code below only works if that inner pack is the first type in the pack though and I need to know how to check every type in the pack if it is nested and then apply the transformation to each.  `TransformNestedPack` is what I'm working on.  The reason for `PackTransformation` is so that `TransformNestedPack` can be reused for any transformation (rotation is just an example I'm using).  So I'm trying to perfect `TransformNestedPack` using the general transformation `PackTransformation`.

```
#include <iostream>

// Rotating a pack N to the left.
template <int, typename> struct Rotate;

template <template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest>
struct Rotate<0, P<First, Rest...>> {
    using type = P<First, Rest...>;
};

template <int N, int K>
struct PositiveModulo : std::integral_constant<int, (N % K + K) % K> {};

template <int N, template <typename...> class P, typename First, typename... Rest>
struct Rotate<N, P<First, Rest...>> :
    Rotate<PositiveModulo<N-1, sizeof...(Rest)+1>::value, P<Rest..., First>> {};

enum {Rot, Rev, /* ... */};  // enum values for each type of pack transformation.

template <typename, int, int...> struct PackTransformation;

// Specializations of PackTransformation to carry out each type of pack transformation.
template <template <typename...> class P, int N, typename... Types>
struct PackTransformation<P<Types...>, Rot, N> {
    using type = typename Rotate<N, P<Types...>>::type;
};
// Similarly struct PackTransformation<P<Types...>, Rev> will reverse P<Types...>, etc...

// Attempt to have PackTransformation applied to each inner pack in a nested pack:
template <typename, int, int...> struct TransformNestedPack;

// Normal transformation, because the first type is not a pack:
template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Types, int N, int... Parameters>
struct TransformNestedPack<P<Types...>, N, Parameters...> : PackTransformation<P<Types...>, N, Parameters...> {};

// Specialization for when the first type is a pack:
template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Types, typename... Rest, int N, int... Parameters>
struct TransformNestedPack<P<P<Types...>, Rest...>, N, Parameters...> :
    PackTransformation<P<typename TransformNestedPack<P<Types...>, N, Parameters...>::type, Rest...>, N, Parameters...> {};
// The problem above is that it checks only the first type.  It needs to check EVERY type.

template <typename...> struct Pack {};

int main() {
    using NestedPack = Pack<Pack<int, double, char, long>, char, long, short>;
    PackTransformation<NestedPack, Rot, 2>::type a;  // Rotates NestedPack to the left by 2, but not the inner pack.
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_same< decltype(a),
        Pack<long, short, Pack<int, double, char, long>, char>
    >::value << std::endl;  // true

    TransformNestedPack<NestedPack, Rot, 2>::type b;
    std::cout << std::is_same< decltype(b),
        Pack<long, short, Pack<char, long, int, double>, char>
    >::value << std::endl;  // true
    // The above currently works only if there is one nested pack and that nested pack is the first type.
}
```

I just need to generalize the above by checking every type if it is a pack, not just the first one.

Comment: Looks like a unit test for some compilers templating engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, instead of leaving the primary template of `TransformNestedPack` undefined, make it return the type unchanged if it is not a pack:

```
template <typename T, int, int...> struct TransformNestedPack {
    using type = T; // do nothing for non-packs
};
```

Then transforming a pack consists of 1) recursively applying `TransformNestedPack` to every type in the pack and 2) applying `PackTransformation` to the resulting pack of transformed types itself. Hence:

```
template <template <typename...> class P, typename... Types, int N, int... Parameters>
struct TransformNestedPack<P<Types...>, N, Parameters...> 
      : PackTransformation<P<typename TransformNestedPack<Types, N, Parameters...>::type...>, 
                             N, Parameters...> {};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c11652c8e535c86).

Comment: This excellent solution gets my vote, of course.  But it's not working with different pack templates.  For example, when I try to reverse `Pack<int, char, Group<long, short, Wrap<std::string, short, long>, int>, double, long>`, I don't get the desired `Pack<long, double, Group<int, Wrap<long, short, std::string>, short, long>, char, int>`.  The same problem goes with my rotation example.  This was the point in using the template-template `P` in the solution.

Comment: @prestokeys It works just fine with different pack types. The problem is that your code will treat  `std::string` as a pack and reverse/rotate its template arguments as well; I'm just following suit.

Comment: Ok, got rid of that part with another specialization `struct TransformNestedPack<std::string, N, Parameters...> { using type = std::string; };`